# Does the Guppy transformation stack with the Mulligan?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

When you transform into Guppy you get an effect similar to the Mulligan item: when you deal damage, there is some chance of a blue fly spawning. If I become Guppy *and* get the Mulligan, do they together have a higher chance of spawning blue flies than individually?

Answer (score 1):

From [Rebirth Wikia](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Transformations):

> Isaac turns into his cat Guppy after picking up any three of the following items. In this form, Isaac gains flight and **will produce blue flies every time an enemy is hit with a tear**.

Otherwise, [Mulligan](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/The_Mulligan) "*grants an infestation shot with a 1/6 chance of spawning allied blue flies when tears hit an enemy*".

So in my opinion they can't stack, because being *Guppy* already grants a blue attack fly on each hit done.

**EDIT**:

I know we are talking about Rebirth, but in the previous version of the game, according to the original [Wikia](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Guppy#Transforming_into_Guppy):

> Once transformed, Isaac will gain flight and an **enhanced version** of The Mulligan, which always spawns Attack Flies when he or his familiars' tears strike an enemy.

If they could stack it would mean that you can spawn more than an attack fly, but as the [old Wikia](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Guppy#Synergies) states, "*you can't spawn two flies with one shot*".

In the previous version of the game they didn't stack. And I have no evidence to think they have changed that.

Comment: Thanks for finding that information, but your conclusion doesn't necessarily follow. It could just as easily be that on each hit you get a guaranteed blue fly from Guppy *and* a 1/6 chance of getting *another fly* from the Mulligan.

Comment: In my opinion the Guppy transformation is un upgrade of Mulligan, that's why I don't think they could stack.

Comment: That's fine, but I'm looking for actual facts about how it works.

Comment: The previous wikia says that Guppy is an enhanced version of Mulligan, and different people say they don't stack, so I'm pretty sure of that.

Comment: The quote you just added also doesn't say that they don't stack, *and* it isn't relevant because mechanics have changed. Just provide one authoritative or researched source that actually says something about whether they stack and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: You're hard to please. Ok, I'll try to find a better source.

Comment: The page you linked in your last edit also says "Fly spawning effect stacks with The Mulligan item." Now, I know we're still talking about the first game, but this makes me very unsure about the reliability of your claims.

Comment: It says it stacks, but right below it states "You can't spawn two flies with one shot", and that's the only thing you wanted to know. Anyway I've asked McMillen on his blog, I'll let you know as soon as I have an answer.

Comment: No, the think I wanted to know is "Does the Guppy transformation stack with the Mulligan?" The comment you're talking about is my reasoning for why your conclusion did not follow from the information you cited. And, in any case, the way it worked in the previous game doesn't really matter because some mechanics have changed.

Comment: You asked "if Guppy and the Mulligan together have a higher chance of spawning blue flies than individually", and according to the *Rebirth Wikia* Guppy itself grants a blue attack fly on each hit done. So your further question was about chance of getting another fly, and this is what I've asked McMillen.